# KeyCloak: Connection has been refused by the server. Connection timed out

Tags: timeout, keycloak, quarkus

Occasionally I receive a connection timeout when calling the */userinfo* endpoint of my KeyCloak-Server.

So far, I have no indication what's wrong and what causes the timeouts. There are no errors in the server.log I configured. Also, I cannot reproduce the issue, I just see the errors in the logs of the application trying to authenticate with keycloak.

- Is there some sort of connection limit that my keycloak might use?
- List item

What additional logs can I activate to narrow down the problem?

I am currently on version 17.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try running keycloak in debug mode **kc.sh start --log-level=debug**
 If the /userinfo call reached the keycloak then there will be a debug log for that, you can match the time when error occurred to the keycloak log.
Do you have any other components in between your application and keycloak such as proxy, a DNS server etc ? You would need to check their logs as well.
Also check out this document regarding rest api in keycloak -> https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-community/blob/main/design/rest-api-guideline.md#rate-lmiting

Comment: Unfortunatly, the issue is only present in our production enviroment and I don't really feel comfortble to activate the debug-log in this stage. aren't there any specific access logs?

There are other components in between - But I don't have any access to the logs (and the providers claime there is no issue). Also, since every other system is reachable all the time, I assume the problem lies within keycloak.

Comment: I appreciate the efford, but your post was not helpful.

Activating the Debug-Log for everything will not be helpful. Since the problem is not reproducable I will have to wait until it occurs and then hope that I find something in the debug-logs. But this will be nearly impossible. Most likely it will just slow down the application.

The link to the documentation only states that there is no rate limiting. However this does not answer my question. There could be some ressource limitations in quarkus for example.